# How to reliably determine if a Handle is a terminal in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am using `System.IO.hIsTerminalDevice` to determine if a `Handle` is a terminal and apply colorization if this is the case. I noticed that when forking a process using `CreatePipe` as stream for new process stdin and stdout, this function returns `True` which seems to be the wrong answer: A pipe should not be considered as a terminal. I have tried to track down the issue looking at `System.IO` and `System.POSIX.IO` source code but it ends up in C `pipe` function and lead me nowhere.

Is there a better way to tell if a handle is a terminal? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

Here are 2 programs that are supposed to expose the behaviour I observed:

```
import           Control.Monad
import           System.IO
import           System.Process

main = do
  (in_, Just out, Just err, h) <-  createProcess $ (proc "./test2" [])
                                   { std_in = CreatePipe
                                   , std_err = CreatePipe
                                   , std_out = CreatePipe }
  dump out
  where
    dump h = forever $ do
      ln <- hGetLine h
      putStrLn ln
```

Then `test2 :

```
import           System.IO

main = do
  print =<< hIsTerminalDevice stderr
  print =<< hIsTerminalDevice stdout
  print =<< hIsTerminalDevice stdin
```

Then running the first program:

```
$ ./test
False
False
False
```

I know what's happening: What I am forking is not the program itself but a *docker container*! And I explicitly add `-t` parameter which allocates a tty for the container...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a minimal example to illustrate the problem?  The following program prints "False" twice, suggesting that handles created with `CreatePipe` are *not* misidentified as terminal devices:

```
import System.Process
import System.IO

main = do (Just in_, Just out, err, h) <-
            createProcess $ (shell "cat") { std_in = CreatePipe,
                                            std_out = CreatePipe }
          print =<< hIsTerminalDevice in_
          print =<< hIsTerminalDevice out
```

Comment: The problem is not with the handles returned by `createProcess` but with the ones _inside_ the forked process. As suggested I will put a small example.

Comment: I accept the answer as it lead me to the actual solution :)